# jQuery - IE gives [object Object] error when displaying dialogs

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-dialog

I'm making a page where a jQuery dialog comes up with some inputs and later javascript displays them.  This works fine in:

- Chrome 31
- Opera 18
- Safari 5 (This is really old because I'm using safari for windows)

However, it does not work in Internet Explorer 7-11, or Firefox 26.

**DEMO:** http://bit.ly/1chhvBN
**Error in IE 11:**
[image: Internet Explorer 11 Error]

Any Ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using *inline event handlers* with jQuery?!  Use jQuery to bind your events.

Comment: that's some ugly looking code, fails in firefox also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do *not* use `href` attributes to bind event handlers to elements.  You have jQuery, use that to bind the events.

```
<div id="favorites">
    <a href="#" class="add">+</a>
</div>
```

Then, simply do:

```
$('#favorites a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $( '#dialog' ).dialog({width: 850, height: 300});
});
```

Do the same with the `addToFavorites` button.

```
<a href="#" class="addToFavorites button" style="width: 150px;">Add to My Favorites</a>
```

Then do:

```
$('.addToFavorites').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addToFavorites();
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aRpcL/3/

Answer (score 3):

Use **onclick** instead of **href** for opening the dialog.

```
<a onclick="javascript:$( '#dialog' ).dialog({width: 850, height: 300});" class="add">+</a>
```

**Note:** Try to avoid inline scripting, move the JS code to some function and call it.