# Internet Explorer returns false

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, oracle-apex, eventtrigger, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using a classic report with cards template see [apex site for example](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:3100:::NO). I can get this working on all browsers expect internet explorer. My company is using internet explorer 11.

When a user clicks on a card they should see a modal dialog pop, but on internet explorer they are instead met with the word false. I am using JavaScript to trigger the modals, but I also attempted hard coding the links into the sql for the cards. Neither work. I was able to find a work around, but I had to remove the modal pop-ups and code the links into the sql statement. We have other modal windows working in the application on internet explorer, and I tested this with the same result on my personal apex.oracle.com workspace.

My question is has anyone else experienced this issue and is there a way to get this to work with the modal dialog pages? I have been unable to find anything online to answer my question

[Demo of issue](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=134017:1:3277056243976::NO:::)

SQL:

```
select 
order_id,
initials || title "CARD_TITLE",
initials "CARD_INITIALS",
item_text "CARD_TEXT",
item_subtext "CARD_SUBTEXT",
item_icon "CARD_ICON",
redirect "CARD_LINK"
from   (select 1 order_id,
    ' Examples' title,
    0 initials,
    'CARD TEXT GOES HERE' item_text,
    null item_subtext,
    '<span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-5x"></span>' item_icon,
    'javascript:apex.event.trigger(document,"SUBMITTED")' redirect 
    from DUAL)
```

The rest of the code is default apex code: a custom event using the static id SUMBITTED ; a submit page ; and a branch

Comment: Maybe you should show the code that creates the dialog....

Comment: See updated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struggled with the same problem in IE11 and APEX custom events.

The solution was not do use HREF attribute to bind event handlers to elements.

Instead of this:

```
<a href="javascript:apex.event.trigger(document,'SUBMITTED', '123')">Link</a>
```

Use onclick attribute like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="apex.event.trigger(document,'SUBMITTED', '123')">Link</a>
```

123 is custom data, like some record id.

It would be even better to bind click event with jQuery on page init:

```
<a href="#" class="my_link_class" id="my_link_id_321">Link</a>

$('.my_link_class').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    apex.event.trigger(document,'SUBMITTED',this.id.replace('my_link_id_',''));
});
```

But keep in mind that, if you dynamically refresh APEX report regions (do not reload whole page), then jQuery page initializers won't be executed, and 'my_link_class' elements won't be binded (inside refreshed region).

Some links about it:

[jQuery - IE gives [object Object] error when displaying dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845695/jquery-ie-gives-object-object-error-when-displaying-dialogs)

[Internet Explorer Incompatibility - page just shows "[object Object]" WTH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066733/internet-explorer-incompatibility-page-just-shows-object-object-wth)